# IE8 shows error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the line that uses filter() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, internet-explorer-8

I am using this script to limit the characters on lines 1-3 on my textarea. It works in Firefox and Chrome. But in IE8, it shows an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the line that uses filter() method.

**Here's the code:**

```
var result = jQuery('#result');
var my_textarea = jQuery('#mytext');
my_textarea.on('keyup', function(event){
    var el = jQuery(this);
    var lines = el.val().split('\n').length;
    var chars = el.val().split('').filter(function(v){
        return v != '\n';
    }).length;    
    result.html('You have ' + lines + ' lines and ' + chars + ' chars');    

    if ((lines === 1 && chars > 20) || (lines === 2 && chars > 40) || (lines === 3 && chars > 60)) {
          my_textarea.val( my_textarea.val() + "\n");
    }
});
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` (and several other methods on `Array`) are relatively new and aren't implemented in older browsers - not just IE8, but older Firefox too.

You may be interested in [`array_filter` from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_filter:316), as this produces the same effect.

Then again, looking at your code, wouldn't this be simpler?

```
var chars = el.val().replace(/\n/g,'').length;
```

Answer (score 10):

IE8 doesn't support the Array.filter method.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) has a replacement.

Comment: Does not work in IE8. At the bottom of the page. Supported version says IE9.

Comment: @MotaBOS: That's why it has the replacement function, which will work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Array.filter js polyfill:

```
[].filter||(Array.prototype.filter=function(g,f,j,i,h){
  j=this;i=[];
  for(h in j){~~h+""==h&&h>=0&&g.call(f,j[h],+h,j)&&i.push(j[h])}
  return i
});
```

Jakob E